# Visual Studio with Azure AD: Requests blocked because of wrong tenant

Tags: visual-studio

I am posting this question for educational reasons. I haven't found it in Stack Overflow. I will post the answer immediately after.

**Scenario :**

- You use Visual Studio with **several accounts** (in VS's "Account settings" panel) :

  1. An account **that has your VS license** but is not tied to the authentication system (specifically : Azure AD) on which your project relies at runtime.
  2. An account that doesn't have your VS license but **is somehow tied to the Azure AD** on which your project relies at runtime.
  3. (maybe) Yet another account that provides other services, such as your connection to github. Maybe that account is tied to the Azure AD account, in a corporate environment.
- You start your project **locally**, in Visual Studio.
- Despite running locally, it's a project that will **connect** to one or more services hosted in Azure, by using the correct **Azure AD** authentication.
- Your project seems to have **the correct settings** (connection string, secrets, tokens...). Authentication should work!
- But at service-instantiation time (startup, or query call, etc.) one or more connections fail with a cryptic error message :

> Unauthorized (401);  (...)
> Reason: (Request blocked by Auth your-resource-in-azure: Provided AAD token was issued by the authority
> [aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee] which is not trusted by this
> database account. Please ensure the token has been issued by the AAD
> tenant(s) [00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444].

**Troubleshooting:**

- You double-check that the authentication settings are correct, and they are,
- In Azure AD (in the Azure Portal) you check that the user is part of the correct AD groups,
- You checked that you didn't need to PIM the user (maybe even temporarily) for being able to connect,
- You double-check that there are no issues related to the Browsers used by VS for its various operations.

> (reminder: you can configure at least 3 different browser uses in VS:
>
> 1. The browser used in the IDE to open hyperlinks when you ctrl+click them,
> 2. The browser in which your web project starts : click the drop-down "play" button that you use to start the project and click "browse
>    with..."
> 3. the browser in which your VS accounts authentication is stored : Tools-->Options-->Environment-->Accounts-->"Embedded web browser"
>    versus "System web browser")

- Here is a good explanation on how to fix browser-related issues : https://blog.jongallant.com/2021/08/visual-studio-re-enter-credentials/

> - Tools -> Options -> Accounts
> - In the “Add and re-authenticate accounts using:” drop-down, select “System web browser”
> - Sign out, then sign back in.
> - Restart Visual Studio

- After examining the GUIDs in the error message, **you notice that the tenant expected as the correct authority is not the tenant of the company managing the Azure AD; instead it's the tenant of your other account: the one only meant to provide a VS license.**

How to check the tenant's GUID : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-to-find-tenant

The root issue is clear : **You don't know how to simultaneously tell VS to use the correct account for the license and the correct account for the tenant containing the Azure AD.**

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use the account tied to the tenant as the "main" account** in the "Account settings " panel.

It doesn't matter if the account providing the **license** is the main account. **It can be one of the secondary accounts below.**

this rearrangement will neither prevent VS from finding the license nor from connecting to other secondary services such as github (which maybe provides your precious github copilot license).

**Step by step :**

- In the top-right corner of the VS window, open "Account Settings..."
- Under the "main" account (in the top-left part of the panel), click "sign out"
- click "sign in" and this time log as the account that is in the correct Azure tenant (the one that's expected in the error message)
- (optional) After logging in, click "check for an updated license". Visual studio will fail to find one.
- Still in the "Account settings" popup, under "All accounts", click "Add"
- Add the account that has your licenses.
- Click "Check for an updated license". This time it finds one!
- If needed, add any other account that you might need, such as your company-provided github account (in my case it's inderctly linked to the Azure AD account, which added to the confusion -- same account, but different!)

**This image summarizes what works and what doesn't** (it's redundant to the explanations above) :

[image]

[image]